# Stream not readable

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I'm sorry for not knowing a better way to subject this issue. I can modify once I better understand what is happening. I am trying to use a StreamWriter in the following code block:

```
 public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string fontFileNames)
        {
            // Open the file.
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fontFileNames, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
            //Add string to the file
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            sw.WriteLine ("Test");
            // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
            bool bSuccess = false;
            // Your unmanaged pointer.
            IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
            int nLength;
            nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
            // Read the contents of the file into the array.
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
            // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
            pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
            // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
            bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
            return bSuccess;

        }
```

When I add the stream writer I get a "Stream not readable" error and I'm not sure why. I'm new, so this is probably something elementary. I'm just trying to add a string to a file that I am sending to a printer (as raw PCL). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When do you get that error, during compilation or running? What line does it occur on?

Comment: You opened stream for write only. Use `FileAccess.ReadWrite`. Additionally, you will need to seek stream to 0 offset before read it with `fs.Position = 0;`.

Answer (score 3):

You have some logical errors in your code:

1. You need to open your file as [`FileAccess.ReadWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z36sx0f(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. The [`FileMode.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx) flag indicates that the operating system should open an existing file; however, you subsequently proceed to overwrite the first few bytes of its contents with your `"Test"` string. This is probably not desired behaviour. If you want to replace the file, use `FileMode.Truncate`. If you want to add your string to the end of the file, use `FileMode.Append`.
3. You need to flush the contents of your `StreamWriter` once you're done writing to it.
4. You need to reset your stream's position for your `BinaryReader` to read the written contents.
5. Don't forget to dispose your streams, readers, writers, and (preferably through `using` blocks).

Sample code:

```
// Open the file.
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fontFileNames, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{ 
    //Add string to the file        
    sw.WriteLine("Test");
    sw.Flush();
    fs.Position = 0;

    // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
    {
        /* rest of your code here */
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Sample code with append:

```
// Open the file.
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fontFileNames, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{ 
    //Add string to the file        
    sw.WriteLine("Test");
}

// Create a BinaryReader on the file.
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fontFileNames, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
{
    byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
    /* rest of your code here */
}
```

Comment: Awesome info Douglas. Thanks. I did run into the following error though: "Additional information: Append access can be requested only in write-only mode"

Comment: My fault; I tested with `Truncate` (and have since updated my answer). If you really want to append, then the easiest option would probably be to use separate `FileStream` instances for writing and for reading (closing the former before opening the latter).

Comment: Yeah. It sounds like I will have to read/write separately as I do need to add to an existing file. Sounds a bit difficult for me, but I will give it a try shortly. I have a vague idea of how to do it.

Comment: I still just can't seem to get this thing to append. Feel like I tried every combination. My ignorance is painful on this one.

Comment: @Gernatch: I've added an example with `FileMode.Append`. Check whether you can get it to work; if not, post back with the difficulty you're having.

Comment: What benefit is there in adding "using" at the beginning rather than the way I did it previously? Just curious.

Comment: Hm. Getting "Requested range extends past the end of the array" at this point:  Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);

Answer (score 2):

The issue occurs because you open the `FileStream` with only write access:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fontFileNames, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
```

and then try to read from it with `BinaryReader`:

```
bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
```

Instead open the stream with read/write access:

```
... = new FileStream(fontFileNames, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```